# How do you change where an object is placed when it is created?

Tags: objects, customization, snapping, 3d-cursor

When you add an object in blender (cube, plane, etc), it always positions the object at the 3D cursor. I know you can move the cursor or snap it to another object, but I wanted to know if there is a way to pick where objects are positioned when added, such as always placing them at the active object's origin (I just want objects to always be placed at the center when added, without having to snap the cursor each time).

I did a quick look through the preferences/manual and didn't find anything. It's not a big deal, I just wanted to ask because it seems like something that would be configurable, and it's been bugging me for a while now because I accidentally move the 3D cursor constantly, and it gets annoying if you're adding alot of objects.

Edit: found a good alternative a while ago in case anyone ever needs this. I've just started using 'alt + g' in order to reset the translation, which quickly places the object at the origin.